# Angular POST different response to CURL POST

Tags: angular, typescript, post

I have an endpoint which expects to receive a large amount of data (10mb +) via a post request, and responds with some JSON.  The endpoint is running on ASP.NET and I don't have control over it.

From my machine I can send a sample file via curl, which gets a vaild JSON response, for example:

```
$ cat data.txt | curl -X POST -d "@-" "http://{omitted}/?numtopics=2&topiclength=2&passes=2"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 7611k  100   834  100 7610k     75   691k  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:--   252
{"JSON REPONSE..."}
```

However when I try calling it from Angular I am getting a completely different

```
fileChange(event) {
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = data => {
      this.http.post('http://{omitted}/?numtopics=2&topiclength=2&passes=2', fileReader.result)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(x => {
          return Observable.throw(x)
        })
        .subscribe(
          data => console.log(data),
          error => console.error(error));
    }
  }
```

Here I get the following HTML response instead of the expected JSON response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="./?numtopics=2&amp;topiclength=2&amp;passes=2" id="InputData">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="Qrcz5rvSPx2C1sHcD5F4bac+Uitth2vxAxSPfWdXSaigf52n46StPyoNiNNnVKj9QKodTIPyRCkpLmTDJqDS7XR/DPeNDv96B29H5w6Uxqf6VeCm5FJHNqL98+YGppIz" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CA0B0334" />
</div>
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong in my Angular code?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered what I was missing.  By using verbose mode in curl, I was able to see that it was automatically adding a `content-type` header.  By adding this to the angular POST request, it worked.

The code to add the header is below:

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    fileReader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
    fileReader.onload = data => {
      this.http.post('http://{url}/?numtopics=2&topiclength=2&passes=2', fileReader.result, {headers: headers})
```